# Explicitly select copy assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 if both copy and move assignment are available, the compiler automatically chooses copy assignment if the argument is lvalue and move assignment if it is rvalue. Using `std::move` it is possible to explicitely select the move assignment for lvalue. But how is it possible to explicitely select the copy assignment for rvalue?

Code example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class testClass
{
public:
    testClass &operator=(const int &other) {
        std::cout << "Copy assignment chosen." << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    testClass &operator=(int &&other) {
        std::cout << "Move assignment chosen." << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }   
};  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 4;
    testClass test;

    test = a; // Selects copy assignment
    test = 3; // Selects move assignment

    test = std::move(a); // Selects move assignment
//  test = std::copy(3); // <--- This does not work

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can `static_cast` to `const int&` : `test = static_cast<const int&>(3);`

Comment: @rahnema1 Comment is not for answering, you know...

Comment: @NickyC : Sometimes one only wants to bother writing one sentence, and one sentence is rarely a good answer. ;-]

Comment: If you have both operators, the functionality is written to handle the parameter correct. For that reason it looks not very useful to "manually" select a different operator as the "natural right" one. Like with std::move, it will result in the objects "invalid state". If that is expected, fine! But if handling an rvalue as lvalue?

Comment: I'm curious as to the motivation for doing this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One possible way is to write your own `copy` to bind the object to an lvalue reference:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T& copy(T&& t) noexcept
{
    return t;
}
```

And you can test it this way:

```
test = copy(a);
test = copy(3);
test = copy(std::move(a));
```

You may put this function in your own namespace to keep things clean. You may also choose a better name for it.

---

To address fear of lifetime issue, here is some considerations:

- This `copy` function takes a reference and returns the same reference immediately. It implies that the caller is responsible for controlling the lifetime.
- Lifetime of a temporary object persists until the end of the statement. This makes the object persists long enough to be passed into the left hand side of `=`.

Comment: That looks evil. And I'm not sure if it's defined behavior or not. Does the language guarantee that the lifetime of the `T&&` argument is actually extended? Probably not. I'm not sure. I suspect not, and that this is actually UB.

Comment: @NikosC. - It's no more and no less safe than any messing about with r-values. In a single full expression, it will be fine. It's meant to be used just like `std::move`

Comment: @StoryTeller `std::move` is for lvalues, so their lifetime is guaranteed. This one takes an rvalue, and that might disappear right away. IANALL though...

Comment: @NikosC. - `std::move` takes a forwarding reference. And values don't "disappear right away". You can bind an r-value reference to an rvalue *because* it has some lifetime guarantees.

Comment: @StoryTeller Goddammit... the `&&` in templates always gets me. You are right, of course :)

Comment: @NickyC, so would this mean using `std::copy()` will never work? I think that's one hidden question in the code.

Comment: @codekaizer Such `std::copy` simply does not exist. A non-existing thing obviously does not work. (Although there is a function named `std::copy`, it is not the one we are imagining here.)

Comment: @NickyC, true. I think OPs generalization lead to confusion that it works for `std::move()` but `std::copy()` didn't. Oh well, it doesn't matter now since you provided a good solution. +1

Comment: Since `copy` already has a different meaning in `std`, and since this is really an inversion of `std::move`, I usually call this function `stay` in my utilities.

Comment: @Angew `std::move` also has two meanings ;) (cast to xvalue and move a range to another)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it `copy`, as that looks like it should return a copy! Also, you forgot `noexcept`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 At least those two have different arity.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's for symmetry with `move` (which also doesn't move anything).

Comment: @Cubic At least with `move()` the obvious question is "where to", as the arity is wrong. With `copy()`, that's not quite there.

Answer (score 8):

You can `static_cast` to `const int&`:

```
test = static_cast<const int&>(3);
```

Comment: This has the subtle disadvantage of adding `const`, which fails for things like `std::auto_ptr`. (Which yes, is a completely evil example, but an occasionally useful concept)

Comment: @o11c But since you need to write this code on a case-by-case anyway, including manually figuring out what to replace `int` with, you can choose to omit `const` on a case-by-case basis if you wish.

Comment: @ArthurTacca `static_cast<int&>(3)` fails to compile, and `const_cast<int&>(static_cast<const int&>(3))` is UB if you ever actually do any mutation.

Comment: @o11c Interesting, I didn't realise that!

Comment: @o11c I thought `std::auto_ptr` was deprecated, and maybe even removed in c++17?

Comment: @snb correct, but it's still possible to write classes with a similar copy-assign

Comment: @o11c Oh I think I misunderstood you, you weren't saying that `std::auto_ptr` was useful, just the concept of not failing on classes that fit similar signatures right?

Comment: @snb and o11c The Question is about explicitly selecting the copy assignment for `rvalue`. Constructors of classes such as `auto_ptr` don't have signatures that accept rvalues.So their constructors automatically choose copy assignment and `auto_ptr` can't be a good example for this problem.